# Explain PostgreSQL stored procedures

Tags: windows, postgresql, stored-procedures

I just can't quite get a grasp on them (working with PostgreSQL as of today). Working with version 9.0.4 on Windows, using pgAdmin III.
I have a relatively long experience with MS SQL Server functions and SPs. 
As I've understood so far, there is no direct analogue to MSSQL SP-s in PostgreSQL (however Functions looks just the same). But you can create procedures in other languages which can be built into postgres. So far I was able to produce following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetProduct()
    RETURNS refcursor AS

$BODY$
DECLARE pr_cur refcursor;

BEGIN
    OPEN pr_cur FOR 
        SELECT * FROM "Product";
    RETURN pr_cur;
END;
$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;
```

And use it like this (using Npgsql library):

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=*;Password=*;Database=Warehouse;");
conn.Open();
NpgsqlTransaction t = conn.BeginTransaction();

NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("GetProduct", conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(command);

DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
da.Fill(myDS);

t.Commit();
conn.Close();

myDS.WriteXml("out.xml");
```

It works but I don't understand completely how. First I have not found refcursor in return types of Create function dialog of pgAdmin (is it a synonim to something else?). Second, I still can't manage to get row output in pgAdmin from function:

```
SELECT * FROM GetProduct();
```

works not as expected :). 
Third: does this "function" works same way as SPs of SQL Server (compiled, executes faster, etc.)? Or still this is just some workaround to get almost same behaviour?

And last but not least - any good tutorial for ones migration from SQL Server?

**UPDATE:**

Investigating problem further it's seems like indeed, there is direct equivalent for MSSQL SPs in pgSQL, but you can use functions instead. So one more question now, is it reasonable to use pgSQL functions instead of SPs? As I understand it now, my query return some kind of firehose cursor to result. I've almost never used cursors in MSSQL and know that it's not recommended to do that as it's very inefficient? Or is it some other kind of cursor we dealing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function like this.

```
create function GetProduct() 
returns setof Product as 
  'select * from "Product";' 
language 'sql';
```

And you can get its results like this.

```
select * from GetProduct();
```

If your function doesn't return any data, call it like this.

```
select procedure_name(arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: Well, it's, probably, more close to that a want achieve but still, returned result set differs from raw query "select * from "Product";" - 5 columns, rather than some strange one returned by your query (maybe it's no difference for Npgsql, haven't tested it yet).

Comment: I made a transcription error. You might want to try it again.

Comment: I've noticed and corrected that error in the first try. It returns ONE columnt with all 5 columns data. However I want to recieve 5 columns.

Comment: I agree using a set returning function is probably easier to use than a ref cursor. Note that you should still write `SELECT * FROM GetProduct()`

Comment: However with first variant I can write 'SELECT "ProductName", "ProductBrand" FROM "Product"' and get specified columns, but it doesn't work with this variant.

Comment: If you tried to modify the function to return only two columns, then the return value won't match the return type. It's no longer a `setof Product`.

Comment: Well, that's obvious, but I'm looking for a template code which is most similar to SQL Server SPs, where you can enter just any code, and then call it EXEC sp_name(param1, ...). But after some additional reading it seems like there is indeed not direct equivalent for that in pgSQL. So the only question remains is it reasonable to use Functions insted of SPs in pgSQL at all.

Comment: The function I posted is just sql (`language 'sql'`) , but you can write arbitrarily complex functions in plpgsql. There are two different ways to call a function in PostgreSQL, though, depending on whether it returns any data. See my edit.